# List all IIS items via PowerShell Web Administration cmdlets

Tags: iis, powershell

I am trying to bring back a list representative of an IIS website's structure using the [Web Administration cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx).  What I am after is what you see in the inetmgr (Internet Information Services Manager) treeview. I see that there are cmdlets to [Get-WebApplication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790554.aspx) and [Get-WebVirtualDirectory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807826.aspx), but how do I get plain old folders which may have been created under the root of the site?

Is there some cmdlet that I am missing missing?  Is there a single cmdlet which will just retrieve all of these items as a collection and allow me to interrogate the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to interrogate the IIS listing of sites and go from there, you can always do:

```
cd IIS:\sites
dir
```

Then you can iterate each object for the physical path.

Comment: The physical path will indeed list all folders if I iterate over it.  Is there any way however to get all of this information in one cmdlet?

Comment: No cmdlet that I know of.  You could just do a dir | select {$_.PhysicalPath}